# PHP vTiger Issue creating tickets with vtwsclib

Tags: php, api, vtiger

I am trying to figure out how to programmatically create a "HelpDesk" ticket in vTiger using its Web Services api. I am currently using the official vtwsclib v1.5 php library. The log in, appears to succeed and I can also successfully perform a doDescribe on the module, however doCreate returns 'false' no matter what I do. Sample below. Am I missing anything?

```
$url = 'http://vtiger.mydomain.com/';
$client = new Vtiger_WSClient($url);
$login = $client -> doLogin('systemuser', 'O8nFgnotrealkey');
if (!$login)
    echo 'Login Failed';
else {
    $module = "HelpDesk";
    $record = $client -> doCreate($module, Array(
        'assigned_user_id' => "21",
        'parent_id' => "91",
        'ticket_title' => "test",
        'ticketstatus' => "Open"
    ));

    if ($record) {
        $recordid = $client -> getRecordId($record['id']);
    }
}
```

Retruns:

```
$record: bool(false)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

Looks like if you leave 'assigned_user_id' blank, it will populate it with the correct 'assigned_user_id' for yourself. The 'assigned_user_id' can also be retrieved for your own account from the login response and it appears like this {module_id}x{user_id}. ie: "3x16".

All id's ('parent_id', 'assigned_user_id', 'related_to' etc etc etc) appear to be in a 'NxN' format.